# Adding my outputs for for Purchase Price

Tags: java, input, jvm, output

I'm struggling in my code a bit, I just started learning java 4 weeks ago, I hope I can get some help from u guys please..
first. this is my JAVA CODE

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CoffeeBot
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("Hello, what's your name?");
    String name = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Would you like to order some coffee, " + name + "? (y/n)");
String goon=keyboard.next();
char answer=goon.charAt(0);
if ((answer!= 'y') && (answer!='n'))
System.out.println("no valid");
else if (answer== 'n')
System.out.println("OK BYE");
else{
System.out.println("Great, Let's get started.");
System.out.println("Order selection");
System.out.println("----------------");
System.out.println("There are 90 coffee cups in stock and each costs $2.00");
System.out.println("There are 100 coffee shots in stock and each costs $1.00");
System.out.println("How many cups of coffee would you like?");
int cupsOfCoffee = keyboard.nextInt();
if (cupsOfCoffee ==0)
System.out.println("No cups, no coffee, Goodbye");
else if (cupsOfCoffee < 0)
System.err.println("Doesn't compute, system terminating");
else if (cupsOfCoffee >90)
System.out.println("Not enogh stock,come back later");
else {

  int countd;
  int[] shots = new int[cupsOfCoffee];
  for (countd = 0; countd < cupsOfCoffee; countd++)
  {
      System.out.println("How many coffee shots in cup " + (countd+1 ));

      shots[countd] = keyboard.nextInt();
      while ((shots[countd] <0 || (shots[countd]>100)) ) {
        System.err.println("Try again");
        System.out.println("How many cups of coffee would you like in" + (countd+1));
        shots[countd] = keyboard.nextInt();

      }
  }
  System.out.println("Order Suammery\n----------------");
  for (countd = 0; countd < cupsOfCoffee; countd++)

  {System.out.println("cup " + (countd + 1) + " has " + shots[countd] +  " shots and will cost" + (2+(shots[countd]))) ;

}
System.out.println(cupsOfCoffee + "To purchase");
System.out.println("Purchase price= "  ) ;


System.out.println("Proceed to payment? (y/n)");
String gon = keyboard.next();
char answers=gon.charAt(0);
if ((answers!= 'y') && (answers!='n'))
System.out.println("no valid");
else if (answers== 'n')
System.out.println("OK BYE");

else {
  System.out.println("ORDER PAYMENT\n-----------------");
}


}
}
}
}
```

My program isn't finished yet, but I reached the part where it calculates my total price. For this, I want the total of all my inputs, or the answer of the sum of my outputs (this equation (2+(shots[countd]));

For example if I get the 3 outputs ..... AND WILL COST (4,5,6) so i need the sum of the 4+5+6, .. I tried the sum+= thing, but I think it didn't work, or I might be a beginner so i couldn't use it correctly. So I need some output next the the (PURCHASE PRICE= ) statement

I hope u guys got my point, and i wish some help from u, and I'd appreciate it.

Comment: please fix your indentation. It is really hard to read your code this way.

Comment: to complicate to understand !!!! kindly format it properly

Comment: yea yea I will, but i am still testing it, am just getting my outpiys correct, I'll fix it as soon as i finsh, thanks for the note boys, appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just add a few lines into your code and tried to answer your question, do let me know in case this is what you want.

```
int sum=0; // **new addition**
                for (countd = 0; countd < cupsOfCoffee; countd++)
                {
                    System.out.println("cup " + (countd + 1) + " has " + shots[countd] +  " shots and will cost" + (2+(shots[countd]))) ;
                    sum+=2+(shots[countd]); // **new addition**

                }
                System.out.println(cupsOfCoffee + "To purchase");
                System.out.println("Purchase price= " +sum ) ;// **new addition**
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH BRO ! THATS EXACTLY WHAT  I ASKED FOR !! APPRECIATE IT !!